# PHPmailer multiple addresses from database

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

How to set PHPMailer to send messages to e-mails that are retrieved from the database? 
All emails from DB:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT company_name, email, company_url, company_nip FROM test WHERE company_nip='$nip'");
foreach ( $result as $print )   {
    $c_name = stripslashes($print->company_name);
    $c_url = stripslashes($print->company_url);
    $c_email = stripslashes($print->email);
}
```

PHPmailer:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    require "PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php"; 

    $mail = new PHPMailer(); 

    $mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");
    $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
    $address = $c_email;
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");
    $mail->Subject = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";
    $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
    $mail->MsgHTML("asdf");

    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
       echo "Message sent!";
    }
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
$addresses = explode(',', $c_email);

foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    $mail->AddAddress($address);
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Why are you calling `AddReplyTo()` twice?

Comment: I did it accidentally, already removed.

Comment: You've based your code on an obsolete example and are probably using an old version of PHPMailer. I suggest you look at the [mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).